# I cannot run Gazebo and Rviz Due to Missing sdformat.dll and image_transport.dll

Tags: windows-10, ros

Hello there hope you are all well.

Few days ago I installed ROS on my Windows-10 computer by following the tutorials on their site. I worked with TurtleSim and some other features of ROS without any problem. However when I try to run Gazebo, I get an error saying sdformat.dll is missing. And when I try to run Rviz, I get an error saying image_transport.dll and resource_retriever.dll is missing. I tried updating ROS but it did no good. I asked about this on ROS' official answer site but no one responded. Is there any CMD command or chocolatey feature which I can use to repair missing files? If not, what can I do to resolve this error?

Thank you so much

Comment: Did you refer to this document(http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_windows&cat=install) to install Gazebo on windows?

Comment: No, I followed this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) which contains Gazebo as well. I found on the internet that adding the lib folder to path eliminates the issue with Gazebo. Indeed, it eliminated the issue, however I still have the same problem with Rviz.

Comment: Did you install melodic or noetic? This link(https://answers.ros.org/question/356934/rviz-on-ros-windows-10/) may be helpful for you.